# How do I use foreach to display all images in a specific folder using Ejs view

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have multiple folders located in "upload" folder, each folder has some images i.e. 6 or 5 images

- upload

  - 1:

    - header_image.jpg
    - 1.jpg
    - footer_image.jpg
  - 2:

    - 12.jpg
    - 13.jpg
  - ..

I would like to foreach in each folder and preview all images inside, using .ejs interface and replace ____ in the image name

```
<% data.forEach(function (foldernames) { %>
<img
   src="images/uploads/<%=foldernames.name%>/_______"
/>
<% }) %>
```

Just to let you know, I am using express framework with .ejs views.

Comment: Could you please copy / paste the `data` variable before to pass it to render function please?

Comment: Hey! Welcome to Stack Overflow, it'd be helpful if you could provide more context in your question, such as your expected outcome, what you've tried, and what isn't working. Right now I'm having a hard time figuring out the exact scope because of this. Thank you! :)